# How do I save a matplotlib figure in the normalized [0,1] range?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I am generating annotation files for image segmentation learning. 
For that I am relying on matplotlibs fill_between() method. 
I need to save the figure borderless and in a value range of [0,1] .

How do I do that?

I found out that fig.savefig() can pass arguments to the pillow backend when saving as .png, however i can not find the right arguments to pass to save it in [0,1] range instead of [0,255]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62065477/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* save a png image in a real valued range of `[0,1]`. Image intensity values in RGB format are only defined for natural numbers of `[0,255]`. It would also makes little sense to visualise an image with such low intensity values, because it would appear pretty much black.

What you *could* do instead if you are interested in persisting your data is normalising your matrix to your range and save it as a numpy array instead using numpys [save()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) function.

Comment: The library I am using is specifically asking for [0,1] pngs.
The example images are indeed not viewable, they show up as blaclk in any viewer.

Comment: It is black because a intensity of 0 corresponds to black in any grayscale image. You won't see any visual difference at an intensity of 1. You can't save an image with an intensity of e.g 0.5 though, that's not how this format works. Are you trying to visualise binary images?

Comment: Not at all, I need the images in the [0,1] range, they do not need to be visible

Comment: In that case I'd recommend you save it as an numpy array instead, there is no point in storing it as an image if you du not want to visualize it. There are better formats for that.

Comment: I do not need to visualize it. the library that I need use requires .pngs in [0,1] range